# Writing to internal storage with intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to write a cropped image to the internal storage, but get a `Permision denied`.

Here is the intent:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getBackgroundUri());
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat",Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());

                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, ActivityCrop);
```

Here is the URI to the file:

```
06-25 21:27:46.644: W/GenPrefsFragment(10251): getBackgroundUri(): file:///data/data/de.dawnkeeper.androidwall/background.jpg
```

and here is the error:

```
06-25 21:17:30.238: W/CropImage(9001): cannot write output
06-25 21:17:30.238: W/CropImage(9001): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Permission denied
06-25 21:17:30.238: W/CropImage(9001):  at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
06-25 21:17:30.238: W/CropImage(9001):  at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:117)
```

As far as I know there is no permission required to access the internal storage.

What am I missing?

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

**edit**

I meanwhile found a solution. If I create the file before the intent is started and use `file.setWritable(true,false)` the intend works as .. intended.

I am still accepting Hans Kratz answer as it is a cleaner solution.

Comment: do you have Add to manifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes the permission is in the manifest.

Comment: is it inside out outside of the <application> element?

Comment: Outside. Putting it inside would give me a compiler warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use internal storage because the Media Store Content Provider can not write to the private storage space of your app. Have `getBackgroundUri()` return a path to the external storage, e.g. something like `Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "test.jpg"))`